# How to serve a Wordpress page as a 404 page without htaccess or redirect?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'm attempting to serve a Wordpress 404 page created in Wordpress (i.e. it has a slug). I don't want to redirect to it (via PHP or .htaccess) because sometimes slugs get renamed (and forgotten), so I want to tap into the `404.php` of the theme.

Is there a better way to do this without an iframe? For example, render an entire WP page with a WP function (but not with cURL!).

Now, I'm checking if the slug/page exists, and if so, I render a full-size iframe. Else, the original `404.php` code is executed.

```
<?php
// 404.php
if( get_page_by_path('/not-found') ) {
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Not found</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
            #content { position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="/not-found/"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
} else {

// The original code in the theme 404.php file

}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use [`is_404()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404) conditional tag, with a custom page template for it [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part)?

Comment: We can only touch the 404.php file I'm afraid.

Comment: If the `iframe` solution works, then why don't you still use `get_template_part()` instead of the `html` content? I'm not 100
% sure what's the issue here. You want to show a custom 404 page or?